# Why I'm gettin Cannot insert the value NULL into computed column?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm using EF-Code First and this is my model with Data Annotation:

```
public int Count { get; set; }
public int Fee { get; set; }

[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public int Total { get; set; }
```

Or like this:

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]

public int Total
{
    get { return Fee * Count; }
    private set{}
}
```

When I want to create a new record I'm getting the following error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Total'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
>   The statement has been terminated.

As you can see I'm getting the correct computed value in the Create Action Method with model binder:

[image]

By removing the `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)` and set the computed value from my code it works fine and I see the updated total in the database. But my question is if I can do this without `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)` so what's the `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)` usage?

This works:

```
public int Total
{
    get { return Fee * Count; }
    private set{}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_9) and [here](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/dataannotation-in-code-first.aspx) you can't update a calculated column because it's value is retreived from database and never sent back.

So the solution would be to create another [not mapped](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) calculated property in your model which will be used in your code and keep your `Total` property mapped to the database:

```
public int Count { get; set; }
public int Fee { get; set; }
public int Total { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public int CalculatedTotal
{
    get { return Count*Fee; }
}
```

Comment: if I should remove the DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed) and set the computed value from my code so what's the DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed) usage?

Comment: Computed columns. Take a look [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585330/calculated-column-in-ef-code-first).

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare `public int? Total` to accept null.

Comment: I tried this also in this way I'm not getting the error anymore but still in the database I see the NULL value for Total column. I want to see the calculated value in the database also.

Comment: maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981259/entity-framework-4-1-code-first-computed-calculated-column-not-being-inserted) is your problem. Take a look

Comment: Thanks. I looked that. It suggested that I set a computed column at database engine side but I cannot do this because I'm using Code First and what if I change the model the database will drop and it will recreate again so this is not a good option for me.

Comment: Actually it seems that you just need to remove `DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)` from your code. Because this option tells that this value will be computed by database engine but you're already doing this by code..right?

Comment: My main question is exactly this: if his value will be computed by database engine why I'm getting the NULL value for this computed column in the database??

Comment: Also if I should remove the DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed) and set the computed value from my code so what's the DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed) usage?

Comment: as I understand, this error is because you're trying to update this field...and `Computed` fields are `readonly`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132068/discussion-between-elmer-dantas-and-user5032790).